# 'is a directory' error when trying to pass directory name into function

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

In my bash script, I use find to get the folder names by wildcard:

```
for i in $(find ${directory} -mindepth 1 -type d -name ${wildcard});
do
  stuff=doStuff ${i}
done

doStuff() {
  echo ${1}
  return ${1}'/hello';
}
```

The problem is that when I do this, I get the following error (lets say that ${i} correspond to 'home/me/my_directory'):

```
line 111: '/home/me/my_directory': is a directory.
```

(line 111 is the line with 'doStuff')

I've tried doing this, to no avail:

```
for i in $(find ${directory} -mindepth 1 -type d -name ${wildcard});
do
  stuff=doStuff "${i}"
done
```

Apparently it is because the program is trying to execute the directory, but I just want it as a string that I can manipulate.

Comment: Hmmm....According to the bash man page....The return builtin command in bash is used to used to return an EXIT code (integer) not any type of string parameter.

Comment: You could also try `find "${directory}" -mindepth 1 -type d -name "${wildcard}" -print0 | xargs -0 doStuff`

Comment: **googlers**: another great source for getting this error message is `//a wrong bash line comment` instead of `#a correct bash line comment`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quotes and command substitution are your issues here.

The specific issue you're running into is because the shell is trying to run a command called `/home/me/my_directory` with the environment variable `stuff=doStuff`.
What you really want (if I'm interpreting correctly) is to run `doStuff` with the value of `$i` as an argument, assigning the output to the variable `stuff`. The way to do this is to wrap your command in `$()`. For example:

```
stuff="$(doStuff "$i")"
```

Notice How I also put quotes around everything. This is to prevent the shell from word splitting things you don't want it to word split (it'll turn a single argument of `/foo/bar baz` into `/foo/bar` and `baz`).

Also the output of your function is what gets used as the return value, not `return`.

As you should be using more quotes, you should also add them to everything else. Here is a complete version of your script:

```
doStuff() {
  echo "${1}" >&2
  printf '%s/hello' "$1";
}

IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(find "${directory}" -mindepth 1 -type d -name "${wildcard}");
do
  stuff="$(doStuff "${i}")"
done
```

You have to put the function definition before you try and use it. Shell isn't parsed like compiled programs, where it goes through the file several times. It's top-down.
I've also modified `doStuff` to send the `echo` to STDERR where it will be shown on the terminal, and then the `printf` sends to STDOUT where it will be captured into the variable `stuff`.

Note that this will still have an issue if any of your directories contains a newline. However this is a limitation of the shell. The only character a file path cannot contain is a NULL char (`\0`). However bash and other shells cannot store a NULL char in a string (not all, but many. I know zsh can), so you can't use it as a delimiter.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you have space before/after `=`, it messes up.
e.g. MY_VAR='/some/path' is valid
but MY_VAR= '/some/path' or MY_VAR ='/some/path' is not

Answer (score 4):

That is a good effort but it shows that you are trying to write `bash` as if it were a programming language, when it is actually a simple scripting language. The problem with your `stuff=doStuff arg` construction is that to `bash` it does not mean what you think it means. To `bash`, `stuff=doStuff` is a variable assignment, and `arg` is a command. I suggest you read the following two links:

- [How can I store the return value and/or output of a command in a variable?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)
- [How do I return a string (or large number, or negative number) from a function? "return" only lets me give a number from 0 to 255.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/084)

A working version of something similar to what you have would be

```
doStuff () {
    echo "$1/hello"
}

stuff=$(doStuff "$i")
```

Answer (score 1):

The line giving the error does not do what you think it does:

It first sets the environment variable stuff to the string "doStuff", and then tries to execute ${i} as a command.  And since ${i} is a directory,  that fails with the given error message.