# 'is a directory' error when trying to use readlink

Tags: bash, readlink

I am messing around in bash to try and create a custom PS1 but I'm running into an error when I try to print the absolute path of the directory I am in. I have a directory `$FIRMWARE` which is a symlink. I want to display the resolved symlink in the PS1. I have the following code stripped of other info:

```bsh
export FIRMWARE="/path/to/firmware"

firmware_link() {
    local A
    A="$(readlink ${FIRMWARE})"
    echo $A 
}
```

If I call this function I get

```
> $(firmware_link)
bash: /path/to/firmware: Is a directory
```

I tried following [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131568/is-a-directory-error-when-trying-to-pass-directory-name-into-function) but the recommendations for quotes didn't solve my issue. I get a feeling this is a formatting error or a fundamental misunderstanding of how bash works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying:

```
$(firmware_link)
```

at a `bash` prompt. you are telling `bash` to execute your function, and then process the output from that function as a shell command.  That general technique is called command substitution, and in your example code, creates the error that you note.

Instead, try simply invoking the function:

```
firmware_link
```

The expected output would be:

```
/path/to/firmware
```

To see how the problem is arising, manually enter that directory name at a bash prompt:

```
/path/to/firmware
-bash: /path/to/firmware: Is a directory
```

You may spot the error in your code more readily if you were to simplify it slightly:

```
export FIRMWARE="/path/to/firmware"

firmware_link() {
    readlink "${FIRMWARE}"
}
```

This makes it more apparent that the output from function `firmware_link` is going to be a directory name, not a valid `bash` command.

Comment: Ah ok, I figured it was some misunderstanding with bash return. Thank you!